# PHP Composer not installing - Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php, slim

I just set up `Slim Framework for PHP`, and I'm having a hard time installing the slim/views library through `composer.json`

My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "slim/slim",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Slim Framework, a PHP micro framework",
    "keywords": ["microframework","rest","router"],
    "homepage": "http://github.com/codeguy/Slim",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Josh Lockhart",
            "email": "info@joshlockhart.com",
            "homepage": "http://www.joshlockhart.com/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "phing/phing": "2.*"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-mcrypt": "Required for HTTP cookie encryption"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "Slim": "." }
    }
}
```

When I say 
`composer require slim/views`, I get this error, which I'm not sure what it's talking about:

```
Problem 1
    - slim/views 0.1.0 requires slim/slim >=2.0.0 -> satisfiable by slim/slim[2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.6.1].
    - slim/views 0.1.1 requires slim/slim >=2.4.0 -> satisfiable by slim/slim[2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.6.1].
    - slim/views 0.1.2 requires slim/slim >=2.4.0 -> satisfiable by slim/slim[2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.6.1].
    - slim/views 0.1.3 requires slim/slim >=2.4.0 -> satisfiable by slim/slim[2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0, 2.6.0, 2.6.1].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.0.0, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.1.0, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.2.0, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.3.0, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.3.1, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.3.2, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.3.3, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.3.4, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.3.5, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.4.0, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.4.1, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.4.2, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.4.3, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.5.0, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.6.0, 1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: slim/slim[2.6.1, 1.0.0].
    - Installation request for slim/slim 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by slim/slim[1.0.0].
    - Installation request for slim/views 0.1.* -> satisfiable by slim/views[0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3].
```

The current version of Slim Framework I have is `2.6.1`. One thing I've discovered is that if I specify `"version":"2.6.1"` inside my composer.json, after the `name` tag before running `composer require slim/views`, the `composer require` runs fine and the package gets installed. Not sure what's going on; can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Likely, version defaults to 1.0.0. It'll probably be better if you use your own name ("spanguluri/appname"), and add slim/slim to your list of requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ChrisForrence alluded to, your package name `slim/slim` is colliding with the library with the same name. **Change your package name** to something else and slim will install as expected.

```
"name": "sasanka/my-app"
```

Comment: Thank you! I just discovered I was using Composer in the wrong way so I ended up with this problem.